# Property mediator does not build the payload when $body is used

Tags: request, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mediator

When a property mediator is used to capture the request payload body:
`<property expression="$body" name="resource" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

The property mediator does not recognize $body as content aware and hence won't built the payload. So the property mediator will not capture the body of request payload. (It had been working before).

It's working when using `json-eval($)` instead.
I'm using WSO2 EI 6.6.0.

Anyone has solution for this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the $body XPath variable, you need to access the element of the payload. If you don't access the element then the payload won't be built. For example,

```xml
<property expression="$body//element" name="resource" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

You can find the detailed explanation about the $body variable in [XPath Varialbe - $body](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Accessing+Properties+with+XPath+#AccessingPropertieswithXPath-$body).

As alternatives, you could try out the followings,

1. You can disable chunking before specifying the property mediator with $body, so the payload will be built within.

   ```xml
   <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
   ```
2. You can specify a log full mediator before the property mediator and that will also build the payload.

   ```xml
   <log level="full" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
     <property name="payload_full" expression="$body"/>
   </log>
   ```

Comment: DISABLE_CHUNKING worked! Thanks so much! I got another question: How can I format a **payloadFactory (XML type)** to get the property (It errors when I pass ```<format>$1</format>```.

Comment: @hieulm, open a new question explaining the scenario and error traces. It is good to keep the context separated.

Comment: @hieulm could you please mark this as answered if the solution worked for you?